# Template matching with multiple objects in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I'm trying to find multiple templates in an image using opencv python, according to [this link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html).

But the problem is that multiple points returned for a single object with a slightly difference in position.
Something like this:

[image]

I dont want to use `cv2.minMaxLoc()` because there is multiple templates in image.
I wrote a function that delete the close positions, but I want to know is there any straightforward solution for this problem?
thanks.

Comment: Can't you keep the instance with the best matching score ?

Comment: Because the template repeated multiple time in image, i can't use the best matching score and I should save locations with above a threshold.

Comment: I mean the best among nearby instances (the distance limit can be as large as the template size).

Comment: I know, I'm doing something like that by myself. but its required to write a new function. I'm looking to something more simple.

Comment: ok, seems that you don't need me.

Comment: @Salman Please post your full images?

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/ and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to find multiple matches is to write over the found matches and run the match again. **Edit**: A ***better*** way to find multiple matches is to write over the ***results***. In the first example we fill the matched part of results with zeroes (use ones for SQDIFF or CCORR_NORMED) , and then look for the next match in a loop.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

image = cv2.imread('smiley.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
template = cv2.imread('template.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

h, w = template.shape[:2]

method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED

threshold = 0.90

start_time = time.time()

res = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method)

# fake out max_val for first run through loop
max_val = 1
while max_val > threshold:
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    if max_val > threshold:
        res[max_loc[1]-h//2:max_loc[1]+h//2+1, max_loc[0]-w//2:max_loc[0]+w//2+1] = 0   
        image = cv2.rectangle(image,(max_loc[0],max_loc[1]), (max_loc[0]+w+1, max_loc[1]+h+1), (0,255,0) )

cv2.imwrite('output.png', image)
```

input image:

[image]

use the eyes as template images (since there is more than one eye!)

[image]

output:

[image]

And here is the original way I did it by writing over the image. This way is way is much slower because we do n+1 `matchTemplate` operations for n matches. By one measurement, this technique is 1000 times slower.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('smiley.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
template = cv2.imread('template.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

h, w = template.shape[:2]

method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED

threshold = 0.95

# fake out max_val for first run through loop
max_val = 1
while max_val > threshold:
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    # using top ranked score, fill in that area with green
    image[max_loc[1]:max_loc[1]+h+1:, max_loc[0]:max_loc[0]+w+1, 0] = 0    # blue channel
    image[max_loc[1]:max_loc[1]+h+1:, max_loc[0]:max_loc[0]+w+1, 1] = 255  # green channel
    image[max_loc[1]:max_loc[1]+h+1:, max_loc[0]:max_loc[0]+w+1, 2] = 0    # red channel


cv2.imwrite('output.png', image)
```

output image:

[image]

Comment: If matches occur near the edge of the image in the optimized function, max_loc[1]-h//2 and max_loc[0]-w//2 could be negative, which overwrites the wrong portion of the image and probably causes an infinite loop. Using max(..., 0) seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

While running bfris' method for my own dataset, I noticed that the `while` loop can stuck indefinitely in some special cases so here is my improved version:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

image = cv2.imread('smiley.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
template = cv2.imread('template.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

h, w = template.shape[:2]

method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED

threshold = 0.90

start_time = time.time()

res = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method)

# fake out max_val for first run through loop
max_val = 1
prev_min_val, prev_max_val, prev_min_loc, prev_max_loc = None, None, None, None
while max_val > threshold:
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    
    # Prevent infinite loop. If those 4 values are the same as previous ones, break the loop.
    if prev_min_val == min_val and prev_max_val == max_val and prev_min_loc == min_loc and prev_max_loc == max_loc:
        break
    else:
        prev_min_val, prev_max_val, prev_min_loc, prev_max_loc = min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc
    
    if max_val > threshold:
        # Prevent start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col be out of range of image
        start_row = max(0, max_loc[1] - h // 2)
        start_col = max(0, max_loc[0] - w // 2)
        end_row = min(res.shape[0], max_loc[1] + h // 2 + 1)
        end_col = min(res.shape[1], max_loc[0] + w // 2 + 1)

        res[start_row: end_row, start_col: end_col] = 0
        image = cv2.rectangle(image,(max_loc[0],max_loc[1]), (max_loc[0]+w+1, max_loc[1]+h+1), (0,255,0) )

cv2.imwrite('output.png', image)
```

Comment: Nice workaround. An equivalent way might be to use the `clip` function from NumPy: start_row = np.clip(max_loc[1]-h//2, 0, h). Your preference probably depends on which format you can make sense of when you come back to the code 1 year later.

Answer (score 2):

The same for TS, i've rewrite short python method and his improvement with my canges now we could use it for different methods. Maybe it could be helpfull for someone.

```
import * as cv from "opencv4nodejs-prebuilt-install";
import { Point2, Vec3 } from "opencv4nodejs-prebuilt-install";

enum MethodEnum {
  TM_CCOEFF = "TM_CCOEFF",
  TM_CCOEFF_NORMED = "TM_CCOEFF_NORMED",
  TM_CCORR = "TM_CCORR",
  TM_CCORR_NORMED = "TM_CCORR_NORMED",
  TM_SQDIFF = "TM_SQDIFF",
  TM_SQDIFF_NORMED = "TM_SQDIFF_NORMED",
}
type MethodName = `${MethodEnum}`;

export async function matchImagesByWriteOverFounded(
  haystack: cv.Mat,
  needle: cv.Mat,
  confidence: number = 0.99,
  matchedMethod: MethodName = MethodEnum.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED,
  debug: boolean = false
): Promise<Array<any>> {
  const h = needle.rows;
  const w = needle.cols;
  let minVal = 0;
  let maxVal = 1;
  let minMax, match;
  let matchedResults: Array<any> = [];
  let prevMinVal,
    prevMaxVal = 0;
  let prevMinLoc,
    prevMaxLoc = {};

  const isMethodTypeMaxOrMin =
    matchedMethod === MethodEnum.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED ||
    matchedMethod === MethodEnum.TM_SQDIFF;
  let locType = isMethodTypeMaxOrMin ? "minLoc" : "maxLoc";
  let confidentOffset =
    isMethodTypeMaxOrMin && confidence === 0.99 ? 0.008 : -0.19;
  const finalConfident =
    confidence + confidentOffset < 1
      ? confidence + confidentOffset
      : confidence;

  while (
    isMethodTypeMaxOrMin ? minVal <= finalConfident : maxVal > finalConfident
  ) {
    match = await haystack.matchTemplateAsync(needle, cv[`${matchedMethod}`]);
    minMax = await match.minMaxLocAsync();
    minVal = minMax.minVal;
    maxVal = minMax.maxVal;
    let { maxLoc, minLoc } = minMax;

    if (
      prevMinVal === minVal &&
      prevMaxVal === maxVal &&
      JSON.stringify(prevMinLoc) === JSON.stringify(minLoc) &&
      JSON.stringify(prevMaxLoc) === JSON.stringify(maxLoc)
    ) {
      break;
    } else {
      prevMinVal = minVal;
      prevMaxVal = maxVal;
      prevMinLoc = minLoc;
      prevMaxLoc = maxLoc;
    }

    if (
      isMethodTypeMaxOrMin ? minVal <= finalConfident : maxVal > finalConfident
    ) {
      const xL =
        (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).x >= 0
          ? (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).x
          : 0;
      const yL =
        (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).y >= 0
          ? (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).y
          : 0;
      const xR =
        (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).x + w + 1 >= 0
          ? (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).x + w + 1
          : 0;
      const yR =
        (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).y + h + 1 >= 0
          ? (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).y + h + 1
          : 0;

      haystack.drawFillPoly(
        [
          [
            new Point2(xL, yL),
            new Point2(xR, yL),
            new Point2(xR, yR),
            new Point2(xL, yR),
          ],
        ],
        new Vec3(0, 255, 0)
      );
      matchedResults.push(
        isMethodTypeMaxOrMin ? 1.0 - minMax.minVal : minMax.maxVal,
        (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).x,
        (minMax[locType as keyof typeof minMax] as Point2).y,
        needle.cols,
        needle.rows
      );
      if (debug) {
        cv.imshow("debug", haystack);
        cv.waitKey(0);
      }
    }
  }
  if (debug) {
    cv.imshow("debug", haystack);
    cv.waitKey(0);
  }
  return matchedResults;
}
```