# Chess piece detection On chessboard Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect    [image]

on my chessboard[image]

But can't get it to detect the right piece. The piece is 59x83. It should be detected, but isn't.
I guess i'm missing something here?

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the chess board and chess piece images
img_board = cv2.imread('ccom.png')
img_piece = cv2.imread('bbis.png')

# Convert both images to grayscale
img_board_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_board, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_piece_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_piece, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply morphological operations to extract the chess piece from the board
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
img_piece_mask = cv2.erode(img_piece_gray, kernel, iterations=1)
img_piece_mask = cv2.dilate(img_piece_mask, kernel, iterations=1)

# Find the matching location on the board
result = cv2.matchTemplate(img_board_gray, img_piece_mask, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

# Draw a rectangle around the matching location
top_left = min_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + img_piece.shape[1], top_left[1] + img_piece.shape[0])
cv2.rectangle(img_board, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Result', img_board)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Should pieces with the same color only match or pieces of both colors?

Comment: same color only

Comment: The template needs to be the same scale (dimensions) as the piece on the chess board.  Also you should make a mask (piece white on black background) and use the mask so that the background color does not affect your match. cv2.matchTemplate permits the use of a mask. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried several setups and experimentally found this to work best:

1. Do shape matching ignoring the piece color.
2. Do color matching only on matching pieces.

**1- Shape matching:**

In a similar method to what you have listed, but using the `morphological gradient` to stabilize the matching, a response map is created. The map is thresholded to get the most likely locations (4 in our case as color is not checked).

**2- Color matching:**

Using the absolute pixel-wise difference followed by a threshold (needs tuning) we can decide whether the studied piece's color matches the provided template image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_results(img, rects):
    for r in rects:
        print(r)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (r[0], r[1]), (r[0] + r[2], r[1] + r[3]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

def check_color(img, temp, rect):
    y0, y1, x0, x1 = rect[1], rect[1] + rect[3], rect[0], rect[0] + rect[2]    
    crop = (img[y0 : y1, x0 : x1]).copy()
    diff = cv2.absdiff(temp, crop)
    avg_diff = cv2.mean(diff)[0] / 255        
    return avg_diff < 0.4 # a tricky threshold

def find_template_multiple(img, temp):
    rects = []
    w, h = temp.shape[1], temp.shape[0]

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, temp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.5 # matching threshold, relatively stable.
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        rects.append((pt[0], pt[1], w, h))    

    #Perform a simple non-max suppression 
    rects, _ = cv2.groupRectangles(rects, 1, 1)

    #Flatten list of list to list of elements
    rects = [r for r in rects]   

    return rects


# Load the chess board and chess piece images
img_board = cv2.imread('board.png')
img_piece = cv2.imread('template.png')

# Convert both images to grayscale
img_board_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_board, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_piece_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_piece, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

s = 3
kernel = np.ones((s, s), np.uint8)
#morphological gradient stabilizes the template matching by focusing on the shape's edges rather than its content.
img_board_gray_grad = cv2.morphologyEx(img_board_gray, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
img_piece_gray_grad = cv2.morphologyEx(img_piece_gray, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)


rects = find_template_multiple(img_board_gray_grad, img_piece_gray_grad)

matching_color_list = [check_color(img_board_gray, img_piece_gray, r) for r in rects]

#Keep only matching color rectangles.
matching_color_rects = [r for (r, is_matching) in zip(rects, matching_color_list) if is_matching]


draw_results(img_board, matching_color_rects)


# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Result', img_board)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Images:
Board image and template image after morphological gradient:
[image: Board image after Morphological gradient]

[image: Template image after Morphological gradient]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure any morphological operations are required. You did a good job making the template image and it has a transparent background. You can use the transparency channel of the file to make a mask for the template.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the chess board and chess piece images
img_board = cv2.imread('ccom.png')
img_piece = cv2.imread('bbis.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

mask = img_piece[:,:,3] # use the inverted transparency channel for mask


# Convert both images to grayscale
img_board_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_board, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_piece_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_piece, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h, w = img_piece_gray.shape

# Apply morphological operations to extract the chess piece from the board
#kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
#img_piece_mask = cv2.erode(img_piece_gray, kernel, iterations=1)
#img_piece_mask = cv2.dilate(img_piece_mask, kernel, iterations=1)


result = cv2.matchTemplate(img_board_gray, img_piece_gray, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, mask=mask)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

while min_val < 0.1:

    # Draw a rectangle around the matching location
    top_left = min_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + img_piece.shape[1], top_left[1] + img_piece.shape[0])
    cv2.rectangle(img_board, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    #overwrite the portion of the result that has the match:
    h1 = top_left[1]-h//2
    h1 = np.clip(h1, 0, result.shape[0])

    h2 = top_left[1] + h//2 + 1
    h2 = np.clip(h2, 0, result.shape[0])

    w1 = top_left[0] - w//2
    w1 = np.clip(w1, 0, result.shape[1])

    w2 = top_left[0] + w//2 + 1
    w2 = np.clip(w2, 0, result.shape[1])
    result[h1:h2, w1:w2] = 1  # poison the result in the vicinity of this match so it isn't found again

    # look for next match
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

cv2.imwrite('output.png', img_board)

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Result', img_board)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I added the `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag to `imread` to cause OpenCV to read the transparency data. This is super helpful for you because you can now match both black bishops.

It used to be that you could only use a template mask for `TM_SQDIFF` and `TM_CCORR_NORMED`, but I think those restrictions were remove in ver 4.x. I replaced `TM_SQDIFF` with `TM_SQDIFF_NORMED`. The NORMED versions convert the result values to be between 0 and 1 and it feels a lot like a percentage score.

[image]

I used a trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58514954/9705687) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66848923/9705687) that overwrites the `results` so you can find more matches