# Opencv matchTemplate and np.where(): keep only unique values

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Following the [opencv tutorial with Mario coins](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) I am left with a list of points where the small image is detected into the big image. However, there are lots of "duplicates" in the sense that several regions are positive around the same object.

I would like to remove these "duplicates" by having a function that removes redundant elements from a list of tuples:

If the "margin" parameter of this new function is 10 pixels then the tuples `(522, 114)` and `(523, 114)` are considered duplicates because `abs(522-523)<10` and `abs(114-114)<10`.

This would allow me to count the unique detected objects by the length of the resulting list.

With this data the expected result is `[(522, 114),(191, 178)]`. How could I write such a function?

```
npwhere = [(522, 114),
    (523, 114),
    (524, 114),
    (522, 115),
    (523, 115),
    (524, 115),
    (522, 116),
    (523, 116),
    (524, 116),
    (523, 117),
    (191, 178),
    (192, 178),
    (193, 178)]
```

[image]

A bit more on the code I am using (might be irrelevant to this question)

```
   result = cv2.matchTemplate(targetimg, templateimg, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    loc = np.where( result >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        print(pt)
        cv2.rectangle(scr, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
```

Comment: If this was C++, I'd say use OpenCV's `partition` function, but it doesn't have a python binding.... but [it seems to be](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp#L503) a fairly straightforward function, so shouldn't be hard to reimplement in Python.

Comment: A quick attempt porting `partition` to Python: https://pastebin.com/vvervU4H For your example set of points and criteria you mention in the question, it outputs `(2, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])`

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/ seems robust but non-trivial

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternate method for multi-template matching in Python/OpenCV to that provided at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/. I borrow the images from that example.

My method simply consists of iterative peak suppression (via masking the template matching correlation image) until a threshold is reached in the match value or a given number of matches is achieved. I set the maximum number of matches to 10 and the stopping threshold on the match value to 0.95 (out of 1 as a perfect match). I also set the radius of the masked region to 1/4 of the size of the template largest dimension.

Input:

[image]

Template:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('8diamond.png')

# read template
tmplt = cv2.imread('1diamond.png')
hh, ww, cc = tmplt.shape

# set arguments
match_thresh = 0.95               # stopping threshold for match value
num_matches = 10                  # stopping threshold for number of matches
match_radius = max(hh,ww)//4      # approx radius of match peaks

# get correlation surface from template matching
corrimg = cv2.matchTemplate(img,tmplt,cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
hc, wc = corrimg.shape

# get locations of all peaks higher than match_thresh for up to num_matches
imgcopy = img.copy()
corrcopy = corrimg.copy()
for i in range(1, num_matches):
    # get max value and location of max
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(corrcopy)
    x1 = max_loc[0]
    y1 = max_loc[1]
    x2 = x1 + ww
    y2 = y1 + hh
    loc = str(x1) + "," + str(y1)
    if max_val > match_thresh:
        print("match number:", i, "match value:", max_val, "match x,y:", loc)
        # draw draw blue bounding box to define match location
        cv2.rectangle(imgcopy, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,0), 2)
        # draw black filled circle over copy of corrimg 
        cv2.circle(corrcopy, (x1,y1), match_radius, 0, -1)
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
    
# save results
# power of 4 exaggeration of correlation image to emphasize peaks
cv2.imwrite('8diamond_multi_template_corr.png', (255*cv2.pow(corrimg,4)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('8diamond_multi_template_corr_masked.png', (255*cv2.pow(corrcopy,4)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('8diamond_multi_template_match.png', imgcopy)


# show results
# power of 4 exaggeration of correlation image to emphasize peaks
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('template', tmplt)
cv2.imshow('corr', cv2.pow(corrimg,4))
cv2.imshow('corr masked', cv2.pow(corrcopy,4))
cv2.imshow('result', imgcopy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Correlation Image from Template Matching:

[image]

Final Masked Correlation Image showing masked regions:

[image]

Resulting Matches on Input:

[image]

Textual Output:

```
match number: 1 match value: 0.9954221844673157 match x,y: 70,84
match number: 2 match value: 0.9926357865333557 match x,y: 112,132
match number: 3 match value: 0.9903871417045593 match x,y: 157,89
match number: 4 match value: 0.9901180267333984 match x,y: 67,173
match number: 5 match value: 0.9888120889663696 match x,y: 63,261
match number: 6 match value: 0.9862607717514038 match x,y: 108,219
match number: 7 match value: 0.9856082797050476 match x,y: 152,178
match number: 8 match value: 0.9837512969970703 match x,y: 146,261
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, I'd suggest to use [`cv::partition`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga2037c989e69b499c1aa271419f3a9b34), which takes a sequence of items, and a predicate function which determines whether a pair of objects belongs in the same "cluster". It returns the number of clusters, and a list of labels (one per input item) describing which cluster each item belongs to. Unfortunately, due to being a C++ template, there isn't a Python binding for it.

However, the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp#L503) is quite trivial, and the algorithm is also [described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Here is my quick re-implementation of `partition` in pure Python:

```
def partition(items, predicate):
    N = len(items)
        
    # // The first O(N) pass: create N single-vertex trees
    parents = [-1] * N
    ranks = [0] * N
    
    def _find_root(i):
        _root = i
        while parents[_root] >= 0:
            _root = parents[_root]
        return _root
        
    def _compress_path(i, target):
        _k = i
        while True:
            parent = parents[_k]
            if parent < 0:
                break
            parents[_k] = target
            _k = parent

    # The main O(N^2) pass: merge connected components
    for i in range(N):
        # Find root
        root = _find_root(i)
            
        for j in range(N):
            if i == j or not predicate(items[i], items[j]):
                continue
            
            root2 = _find_root(j)
                
            if root != root2:
                # Unite both trees
                rank, rank2 = ranks[root], ranks[root2]
                if rank > rank2:
                    parents[root2] = root
                else:
                    parents[root] = root2
                    ranks[root2] += 1 if rank == rank2 else 0
                    root = root2
                assert parents[root] < 0

                _compress_path(j, root)
                _compress_path(i, root)
                    
    # Final O(N) pass: enumerate classes
    labels = [0] * N
    nclasses = 0

    for i in range(N):
        root = _find_root(i)
        # re-use the rank as the class label
        if ranks[root] >= 0:
            ranks[root] = ~nclasses
            nclasses += 1
        labels[i] = ~ranks[root]

    return nclasses, labels
```

To test this, let's use your description of the predicate:

> If the "margin" parameter of this new function is 10 pixels then the tuples (522, 114) and (523, 114) are considered duplicates because abs(522-523)<10 and abs(114-114)<10.

One way to express this in Python would be

```
def predicate(pt1, pt2):
    threshold = 10
    return (abs(pt1[0] - pt2[0]) < threshold) and (abs(pt1[1] - pt2[1]) < threshold)
```

Now we can run the function on your example set of points.

```
points = [(522, 114),
    (523, 114),
    (524, 114),
    (522, 115),
    (523, 115),
    (524, 115),
    (522, 116),
    (523, 116),
    (524, 116),
    (523, 117),
    (191, 178),
    (192, 178),
    (193, 178)]
    
cluster_count, labels = partition(points, predicate)
for point, label in zip(points, labels):
    print(point, label)
```

And get the following output:

```
(522, 114) 0
(523, 114) 0
(524, 114) 0
(522, 115) 0
(523, 115) 0
(524, 115) 0
(522, 116) 0
(523, 116) 0
(524, 116) 0
(523, 117) 0
(191, 178) 1
(192, 178) 1
(193, 178) 1
```

Now it's up to you to decide how to determine the position for each cluster.