# OpenCV Template Matching Multiscale for Cuda

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

There is little documentation for Python for its use in CUDA. The script below works great for template matching, but when I have more than one of the same object, unfortunately I only prefer one and can find it. Is there a method to use multiscale for cuda?

```
f_gmat.upload(gpu_frame)
t_gmat.upload(template_frame)

t_matcher = cv2.cuda.createTemplateMatching(cv2.CV_8UC1, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
t_res = t_matcher.match(f_gmat, t_gmat)
g_res = t_res.download()
min_valg, max_valg, min_locg, max_locg = cv2.minMaxLoc(g_res)
```

Comment: Does this help --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368951/opencv-matchtemplate-and-np-where-keep-only-unique-values/67374288#67374288 It is just OpenCV not Cuda.

Comment: @fmw42 I want to do the same with cuda but I can't find any documentation

Comment: question is unclear. multiple templates, or multiple scales?