# Opencv matchTemplate couldn't find bush inside map

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to find 2d images of bush inside a 2d map. According to their website I used this code

```
image = cv2.imread('images/Pallet_Town.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
template = cv2.imread('images/Bush (small).png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

print(image.shape)
w, h, _ = template.shape

result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where(result >= threshold)
print(*loc[::-1])
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite('images/result.png', image)
```

The code doesn't work and is not able to find any bush. The result image has no rectangles. What else function should I use to find the bush inside the image (Be it an opencv function or any other package) or is it my code problem.

Using these images (Bush is under the map)

[image: Map]

Bush: [image: Bush]

Comment: Is the bush template in the right scale? Same size as any bush in the image? The missing background in the bush template might be an issue.

Comment: @Micka Yes the bush(16x16) is of the same scale in map. Luckily I have found the answer

Comment: use `TM_SQDIFF`. why is everyone using those rubbish modes? is there some youtube tutorial video that tells everyone to do this?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I only used it because in the opencv docs for Template Matching with Multiple Objects they have used cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED. I just took the code from there (almost) and hence used the same function

Comment: thanks. that's good to know. I found the section you mean. I wish that tutorial would discuss these modes more mathematically. perhaps I should open an issue about that...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I completely agree I am still not sure which method to use on occasions they have not explained it nicely. Do you know a website that mention the correct usage and explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually found the answer, As fmw42 suggested me in comments making a mask of the bush and hence using this code I got the answer. Later I also had to increase the threshold to 0.9. Alternatively reducing threshold to 0.24 also worked but for different images it would have different thresholds which I didn't want

```
image = cv2.imread('images/Pallet_Town.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
template = cv2.imread('images/Bush (small).png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

bush = template[:, :, 0:3]
alpha = template[:, :, 3]
alpha = cv2.merge([alpha, alpha, alpha])
result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, bush, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=alpha)
w, h, _ = template.shape

threshold = 0.9
loc = np.where(result >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite('images/result.png', image)
```

[image: result.png]

Comment: Your template has a transparent background. But your matchTemplate is not using the mask from the transparency alpha channel. So you are matching with the background from whatever is under the transparency, which likely does not match the area around the bush well. In your template that background is black and your bushes have a white background. So either change the template background to white or use the mask from the alpha channel in the matchTemplate(). See the documentation for matchTemplate for the use of a mask image.

Comment: See my example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368951/opencv-matchtemplate-and-np-where-keep-only-unique-values/67374288#67374288 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200

Comment: @fmw42 I couldn't understand how you created a mask of the objects like chess pieces, can you write an answer for my question and explain how I can create a mask for my bush

Comment: Extract the alpha channel from your template and use that. `mask=bush[:,:,3]` and `bush=bush[:,:,0:3]` so that bush is just the bgr channels.

Answer (score 2):

Your template has a transparent background. But your matchTemplate is not using the mask from the transparency alpha channel. So you are matching with the background from whatever is under the transparency, which likely does not match the area around the bush well. In your template that background is black and your bushes have a white background. So either change the template background to white or use the mask from the alpha channel in the matchTemplate(). See the documentation for matchTemplate for the use of a mask image (last argument in the following) in Python/OpenCV:

```
result  =   cv.matchTemplate(   image, templ, method[, result[, mask]]  )
```

So take your template image (the bush):

[image]

and extract the alpha channel and keep only the BGR channels for the image:

```
mask = template[:,:,3]
```

[image]

```
template = template[:,:,0:3]
```

[image]

Do not convert to grayscale. matchTemplate can work with color images.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your answer and wrote my own answering my own question (lol) explaining my new code. Thanks a lot