# How to group an array of coordinates into multiple arrays by proximity?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pyautogui

So I'm trying to make a program that reads an image, masks a certain color (brown in this case) and then gives me the coordinates to those masks. I plan on making the mouse move to those coordinates and click them. Here's what I have done so far:

```
import pyautogui as pygui
import cv2
import numpy as np

# take screenshot

image = cv2.imread("bloodweb.png")
# read image

lower_brown = np.array([29, 39, 52], dtype = "uint8")
upper_brown = np.array([33, 44, 60], dtype = "uint8")
# define BGR boundaries

mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_brown, upper_brown)
# create binary mask
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask =  mask) 
# create mask

cv2.imwrite("bloodweb_mask.png", output)
# save masked image
img = cv2.imread("bloodweb_mask.png")
# read masked image
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
# convert image to grayscale
img = img.astype(np.uint8)


coord = cv2.findNonZero(img)
# find coordinates of masked image
```

As you might expect, I'm getting a enormous list of coordinates and most of them are really close by and I would like to only have one coordinate stored for each location, so I can move the mouse there and click it.

---

Raw image:
[image]

Mask:
[image]

Comment: bould be great to have the images both the original and masked to see how it is. you could use blobdetection to create blobs if pixels are conected, but there's chance that you'll need to morphological operate first (to delete small point, connect or separate areas)

Comment: @UlisesBussi added the images

Comment: you know the number of groups?

Comment: i know only that the maximum number of groups is 30, but they are going to keep changing

Comment: go for blob detection with morphological operations

Comment: Something like OpenCV's [`partition`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga2037c989e69b499c1aa271419f3a9b34) based on distance, but unfortunately that's not available in the Python API AFAIK. I have a feeling i might have done this in Python long time ago (let me have a look), but there's bound to be a library that contains similar algorithm. | Ok, found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67370239/3962537

Comment: Here is a quick prototype based on what I refer to in previous comment: https://pastebin.com/sABvda2U That produces the following result: https://i.imgur.com/cJQ1TID.png | Let me know if it's worth investing more time into writing up a proper answer.

Comment: If you want to detect a certain colour, consider to convert to HSV colour space first.

Comment: @DanMašek oh wow that's perfect, i really want to know more about this prototype

Comment: It works off the mask, so it's up to you to tailor the mask generation algorithm to the images you want to process. I'm on the road until the weekend, I'll write something up when I get home. Meanwhile couple of useful links explaining the algorithm are in the answer I linked to earlier.