# Grouping coordinates based on proximity using Python's NumPy and OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, grouping, coordinates

In python3, I have those kinds of coordinates (x,y), whisch represents points on image:

Detected lines:

```
[
(3196, 1267), (3196, 10), 
(2132, 1157), (2132, 36), 
(1069, 1257), (1069, 0), 
(1068, 764), (1068, 3), 
(7, 1048), (7, 64), 
(1065, 1147), (1065, 0), 
(1066, 1141), (1066, 28), 
(3194, 1263), (3194, 10), 
(2129, 1128), (2129, 22), 
(6, 794), (6, 18), 
(8, 1107), (8, 142), 
(3192, 1264), (3192, 12), 
(9, 1127), (9, 189), 
(10, 1127), (10, 190), 
(3195, 1261), (3195, 9), 
(2131, 1042), (2131, 38), 
(2130, 1098), (2130, 38), 
(3188, 1110), (3188, 173), 
(3191, 1264), (3191, 199), 
(3190, 1264), (3190, 173), 
(11, 1126), (11, 158), 
(3193, 1064), (3193, 11), 
(3189, 1110), (3189, 172)
]
```

I got those points by:

```
# Use Hough Line Transform to detect the lines
# minLineLength - which is the minimum length of a line that will be considered by the algorithm
# maxLineGap - which is the maximum gap between two points on a line that will be accepted by the algorithm.
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho = 1, theta = np.pi/180, 
                        threshold = 60, minLineLength = 700, maxLineGap = 200) 

coordinates = [] #lets define a list of tuple
    
# Draw lines on the input image 
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0] 
    angle = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180. / np.pi
    if angle < 210 and angle > 150:  
        # draw the line
        continue
    elif angle < 50 and angle > -50: 
        # draw the line
        continue
    else: #we only draw the line if it is vertical +/- some degrees (we want to skip horizontal lines)
        # discard the line
        cv2.line(colored_cropped_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2) #lets draw the line
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #set font
        size = 5 #set font size
        rangle = round(angle,1) #lets round angle
        font_scale = size/10 #how much to scale font
        thickness = size #lets set thickness also
        color = (0, 255, 0) #text font color
        image = cv2.putText(colored_cropped_image, str(rangle), (x1, y1), font, font_scale, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        coordinates.append((x1, y1)) #add to tuple
        coordinates.append((x2, y2)) #add to tuple
        continue
```

Grouped together:

```
{
3100: [(3196, 1267), (3196, 10), (3194, 1263), (3194, 10), (3192, 1264), (3192, 12), (3195, 1261), (3195, 9), (3188, 1110), (3188, 173), (3191, 1264), (3191, 199), (3190, 1264), (3190, 173), (3193, 1064), (3193, 11), (3189, 1110), (3189, 172)], 
2100: [(2132, 1157), (2132, 36), (2129, 1128), (2129, 22), (2131, 1042), (2131, 38), (2130, 1098), (2130, 38)], 
1000: [(1069, 1257), (1069, 0), (1068, 764), (1068, 3), (1065, 1147), (1065, 0), (1066, 1141), (1066, 28)], 
0: [(7, 1048), (7, 64), (6, 794), (6, 18), (8, 1107), (8, 142), (9, 1127), (9, 189), (10, 1127), (10, 190), (11, 1126), (11, 158)]
}
```

For grouping i used:

```
result = {} #for the results

#let sort it before
#sorted_result = {z:result[z] for z in sorted(result)}

for x, y in coordinates:
    x_key = x // 100 * 100    # Round x value down to nearest 50
    if x_key not in result:  #Check if x_key already exists in result
        result[x_key] = []     # Create new x_key if it does not exist
    result[x_key].append((x, y)) # Add x, y pair to corresponding x_key
```

[image: real life usage]

The real life usage shoud be to find and group lines together (there could be multiple lines one one actual cutting line).

In  this example (my initial grouping) there is a error when grouping together lines just by fixed pockets, because if a there is 2 points, for example 1599 and 1601 - then we get 2 groups (1500-1600 and 1600-1700), but would like to have only 1 (by proximity). So, it's not a solution.

For example, here it "reads" close lines together (#6 and #7 line):

[image: grouping]

And the data is:

```
[
(2235, 1281), (2235, 20), 
(2875, 1283), (2875, 445), 
(964, 1281), (964, 3), 
(2552, 1282), (2552, 0), 
(2555, 1282), (2555, 413), 
(1915, 1220), (1915, 0), 
(961, 1255), (961, 246), 
(1918, 1160), (1918, 0), 
(1919, 1257), (1919, 313), 
(1279, 1219), (1279, 2), 
(2232, 1283), (2232, 153), 
(2872, 1219), (2872, 38), 
(646, 1173), (646, 284), 
(643, 1281), (643, 4), 
(1597, 1211), (1597, 32), 
(960, 1255), (960, 8), 
(2873, 1127), (2873, 27), 
(642, 1284), (642, 133), 
(3193, 1284), (3193, 3), 
(1600, 1255), (1600, 73), 
(2553, 1255), (2553, 1), 
(3192, 1204), (3192, 4), 
(3191, 1284), (3191, 6), 
(1281, 1200), (1281, 2), 
(1282, 1205), (1282, 86), 
(325, 1177), (325, 110), 
(0, 57), (19, 1201), 
(326, 1206), (326, 366), 
(2876, 1203), (2876, 85), 
(328, 738), (328, 25), 
(644, 1203), (644, 0), 
(2233, 1200), (2233, 21), 
(324, 1200), (324, 1), 
(5, 716), (5, 4), (1599, 955), 
(1599, 32), (1916, 1206), 
(1916, 20), (965, 1203), 
(965, 30), (3188, 1203), 
(3188, 78), (3190, 1179), 
(3190, 8), (1598, 1179), 
(1598, 31), (3187, 1202), 
(3187, 382), (0, 225), 
(16, 1172), (1280, 1193), 
(1280, 1), (1, 21), 
(21, 1174), (2551, 1195), 
(2551, 39), (2234, 1171), 
(2234, 20), (0, 129), 
(18, 1182), (3186, 1192), 
(3186, 383), (3189, 1192), 
(3189, 8), (323, 820), 
(323, 5), (1278, 1179), 
(1278, 3), (11, 1165), 
(11, 12), (2, 21), 
(23, 1258)
]

    {
    2200: [(2235, 1281), (2235, 20), (2232, 1283), (2232, 153), (2233, 1200), (2233, 21), (2234, 1171), (2234, 20)], 
    2800: [(2875, 1283), (2875, 445), (2872, 1219), (2872, 38), (2873, 1127), (2873, 27), (2876, 1203), (2876, 85)], 
    900: [(964, 1281), (964, 3), (961, 1255), (961, 246), (960, 1255), (960, 8), (965, 1203), (965, 30)], 2500: [(2552, 1282), (2552, 0), (2555, 1282), (2555, 413), (2553, 1255), (2553, 1), (2551, 1195), (2551, 39)], 
    1900: [(1915, 1220), (1915, 0), (1918, 1160), (1918, 0), (1919, 1257), (1919, 313), (1916, 1206), (1916, 20)], 
    1200: [(1279, 1219), (1279, 2), (1281, 1200), (1281, 2), (1282, 1205), (1282, 86), (1280, 1193), (1280, 1), (1278, 1179), (1278, 3)], 
    600: [(646, 1173), (646, 284), (643, 1281), (643, 4), (642, 1284), (642, 133), (644, 1203), (644, 0)], 
1500: [(1597, 1211), (1597, 32), (1599, 955), (1599, 32), (1598, 1179), (1598, 31)], 
    3100: [(3193, 1284), (3193, 3), (3192, 1204), (3192, 4), (3191, 1284), (3191, 6), (3188, 1203), (3188, 78), (3190, 1179), (3190, 8), (3187, 1202), (3187, 382), (3186, 1192), (3186, 383), (3189, 1192), (3189, 8)], 
    1600: [(1600, 1255), (1600, 73)], 
300: [(325, 1177), (325, 110), (326, 1206), (326, 366), (328, 738), (328, 25), (324, 1200), (324, 1), (323, 820), (323, 5)], 
    0: [(0, 57), (19, 1201), (5, 716), (5, 4), (0, 225), (16, 1172), (1, 21), (21, 1174), (0, 129), (18, 1182), (11, 1165), (11, 12), (2, 21), (23, 1258)]
    }
```

And with partition and predicate (one answer) there will be error also in case where there are two real life inclined lines too close to each-other (then some of the points from one line could match others x coordinate). Sry, have no image for it, must imagine.

So, we need somehow group line points smarter together. Ideas?

But I'd like to group those somehow smarter, to group coordinates which are near to each other in 25px.

How should it done?

---

The real life usage is to check if the line (which consists points) is in the expected area or not.

Comment: Maybe using [partition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67370239/3962537) function (you just need to change the predicate to one that represents your "near to each other in 25px").

Comment: Thnx, I'll try this out

Comment: I'd ***REALLY*** like to see the input image you extract these points from. -- this sounds like it's just some clustering. the usual stuff applies: cluster to get a fixed k number of clusters, or cluster given some distance threshold.

Comment: Christoph, see latest answer, I posted real life data and also image.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour]. answers are for answering. this isn't a forum thread where you "add a post".

Comment: Sry, my mistake, i'll take the tour.

Comment: Now I deleted my own answer and edited initial question and added details :)

Answer (score 0):

If you stare at the numbers for long enough (I reformatted the numbers in your question to emphasize this), you'll notice that it's always a point pair, same X, different Y. So, only one of four values actually matters for the clustering, the X coordinate.

```
# the points
pts = np.array(pts)

# point pairs
pts = pts.reshape((-1, 2, 2))

# take the interesting values
numbers = pts[:,0,0]

# sort them, look at how they're distributed
numbers = np.sort(numbers)
print(numbers)

# look for large gaps
steps = np.diff(numbers)
print(steps)

# there are steps of upto 4, and steps of around 256
print(np.sort(steps))

# that makes sense when you look at the data
threshold = 128

# get indices of large steps (index falls on left-hand element or a step)
(stops,) = np.nonzero(steps > threshold)

# get the values on either side of a large step, average
# that's a separator
separators = (numbers[stops] + numbers[stops+1]) / 2

# bins:
bins = [numbers.min(), *separators, numbers.max()+1]

# that's counting them into the bins
(hist, _) = np.histogram(numbers, bins=bins)

# and get a bin index for each number:
labels = np.digitize(numbers, bins)
```

```
# numbers (sorted)
array([   6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,   12,  269,  270,  271,  273,  536,  537,  538,  539,  540,  542,  800,
        801,  802,  803,  804,  805,  806,  807,  811, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1332,
       1333, 1334, 1335, 1336, 1598, 1599, 1600, 1601, 1602, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1869, 1870, 1871, 2131, 2132, 2133,
       2134, 2135, 2137, 2138, 2139, 2141, 2396, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2400, 2401, 2663, 2664, 2665, 2666, 2667, 2668,
       2669, 2670, 2671, 2930, 2931, 2933, 3193, 3194, 3195, 3196, 3197, 3198, 3199, 3203])

# steps
array([  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 257,   1,   1,   2, 263,   1,   1,   1,   1,   2, 258,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,
         1,   1,   4, 255,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 258,   1,   1,   1,   1, 262,   1,   1,   1,   1,
       263,   1,   1,   2,   1,   1, 260,   1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   1,   1,   2, 255,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 262,
         1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 259,   1,   2, 260,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   4])

# stops
array([ 6, 10, 16, 25, 34, 39, 44, 50, 59, 65, 74, 77], dtype=int64)

# bins
[6, 140.5, 404.5, 671.0, 938.5, 1203.0, 1467.0, 1733.5, 2001.0, 2268.5, 2532.0, 2800.5, 3063.0, 3204]

# hist
array([7, 4, 6, 9, 9, 5, 5, 6, 9, 6, 9, 3, 8], dtype=int64)

# labels
array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,
        5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
        9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
       13, 13], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I added information to initial question. please see, it explains.